# Word Count in MS Excel 2010

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, word-count

Is there a function built in to count the number of words used in [ms-excel-2010](/questions/tagged/ms-excel-2010) ?

And more specifically the number of words in a selected range ?

Currently, I copy my range out into [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word) to get a count of words used.

[image]

**Note. I'm not interested in number of characters etc. just the count of words.**

Comment: Would consider a **word** to be a set of characters separated by one or more spaces?

Comment: yeah pretty much, for example a number 5 in MS word count is considered a word, I just want something as close to that as possible really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of digging around forums I found the below code that works pretty close to what I was seeking:

```
Sub CountWords()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim CellCount As Long
    Dim TotalWords As Long
    Dim NumWords As Integer
    Dim Raw As String

'ACTIVE SELECTION
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveWindow.Selection.Address)
    TotalWords = 0

    For CellCount = 1 To MyRange.Cells.Count

    If Not MyRange.Cells(CellCount).HasFormula Then

    Raw = MyRange.Cells(CellCount).Value
    Raw = Trim(Raw)
    If Len(Raw) > 0 Then

    NumWords = 1

    Else

    NumWords = 0

    End If

    While InStr(Raw, " ") > 0
    Raw = Mid(Raw, InStr(Raw, " "))
    Raw = Trim(Raw)
    NumWords = NumWords + 1

    Wend

    TotalWords = TotalWords + NumWords

    End If

    Next CellCount

    MsgBox "There are " & TotalWords & " words in the selection."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

With some text in **C1**,in **D1** enter:

```
=LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C1)," ",""))+1
```

[image]

This can easily be modified to handle more than one cell.

**EDIT#1:**

To do this for all of column **C** use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(C:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C:C)," ",""))+1)*(C:C<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: this would work very well for one cell, but I need to select a range of a lot cells, upvoted for effort tho

Comment: @User91504  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Really nice.  I'll throw in a +1 as well. :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch  Thanks........the interesting part is the use of `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: Yes. It's interesting and insightful.  Wish I could vote twice.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

While you have already found a solution, try this UDF as well. Not extensively tested though. It will ensure that excess spaces just in case (e.g. accidentally entered more than one space between words) does not count towards word count and also Value from formula cells outcome is factored in.

```
Public Function GetWordCount(r As Range) As Long

   Dim strTest As String
   Dim strArray() As String
   Dim intCount As Long
   Dim WordCount As Long
   WordCount = 0

   For Each cell In r

    strTest = cell.Value
    strArray = Split(strTest, " ")

    For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
       strArray(intCount) = Trim(strArray(intCount))
    Next

    For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
       If strArray(intCount) = "" Then
       Else
         WordCount = WordCount + 1
       End If
    Next

    Next cell
   GetWordCount = WordCount

End Function
```

[image]